# TinyMCE iframe doesn't be shown

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have a problems with tinyMCE editor.

I want to embed a youtube Video as Iframe, But the video isn't shown in edit mode, edit mode looks like this:

[image]

And in live mode there is only the iframe code shown. What can I do to solve this?

[image]

Problem is that in the view the code looks like this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jkMUwoIQ2wI" width="560" height="315"></iframe>
```

UPDATE:
tinyMCE init js code:

```js
var tinyMCEOptions = {
    mode : "exact",
    elements: "tinyMCE",
    plugins : 'advlist autolink link image lists charmap textcolor print preview media code',
    menubar: "edit insert format view",
    toolbar: [ "undo redo bold italic underline strikethrough forecolor backcolor aligncenter alignright alignjustify | cut copy paste bullist numlist outdent indent blockquote removeformat subscript superscript",
    " styleselect formatselect fontselect fontsizeselect | image media | code"],
    entity_encoding : "raw",
    extended_valid_elements:"iframe[src|title|width|height|allowfullscreen|frameborder|class|id]"
}
```

`extended_valid_elements:"iframe[src|title|width|height|allowfullscreen|frameborder|class|id]",`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because there is an iframe filter for TinyMCE.

You have to change the filter so iframes not filtered.

Look here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62729/when-switching-from-html-to-visual-editor-the-iframe-tag-gets-corrupted

*edit*

Open file: `tinymce/plugins/media/plugin.min.js`

Find: `a.parser.addNodeFilter("iframe,video,audio,object,emb`

Replace with: `a.parser.addNodeFilter("video,audio,object,emb`

Save and try again.

Comment: I've tried to add this: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:extended_valid_elements but nothing changed

Comment: How did you add it? New elements should be added with a Comma (,). Have you tried the first answer in my given URL with the before_init inside the add_filter method?

Comment: yes of course i seperated with comma. No I haven't tried because I didn't really understand it where I should paste the code snipped

Comment: I found out, that if you remove the media plugin, it will work. Seems like the media plugin changes the iframe to an image.

Comment: I edited the solution so you don't have to remove the media plugin. Keep in mind: You won't be able to filter it in the further, because we removed it. You also can remove the extended_valid_elements option.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/premium/pageembed/

Open the link and set configure according to TinyMCE doc

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  plugins: 'pageembed',
  menubar: 'view',
  toolbar: 'pageembed'
});
```